# Get data from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables with a pivot table

Table **user**

id | name | email

Table **drinks**

id | name | price

Pivot Table **user_drinks**

id | user_id | drink_id | quantity | price | status

**Drink Model**

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_drinks', 'drink_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('price', 'quantity')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function drinks()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Drink', 'user_drinks', 'drink_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('price', 'quantity')->withTimestamps();
}
```

I want to get the latest users that have bought drinks and the price and quantity from pivot table e.g

User 1 with name John has bought 2 cups of coffee at $50 dollars

User 2 with name Jane has bought 3 cups of coffee at $75 dollars

Comment: use belongstomany relation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please post your best attempt at working code with the specific errors you come accross.

Answer (score 0):

use this relation to the User model

```
public function drinks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Drink::class, 'user_drinks')->withPivot(['quantity', 'price','status'])->withTimestamps();
}
```

to get it:

```
$user = User::with(['drinks' => function ($q) {
  $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}])->orderByDesc('drinks.created_at')->get();
```

Comment: @Yaskur thank you but this returns all the drinks the first user has bought, i want to get the latest drinks bought by any user

Comment: Yaskur, now it returns users that haven't bought drinks yet, i just need those that have bought drinks. I've edited my question. Thanks